# Why does Monero require synchronization, but Bitcoin doesn't?

Tags: daemon, synchronization, remote-node

I'm wondering why Monero requires "synchronization" while Bitcoin doesn't? I'm asking only about the case when a remote node is used, because it's obvious that local blockchain will require synchronization. In the case with Bitcoin (for example electrum wallet), I can open the wallet after a month of inactivity and it will be ready to use almost immediately, unlike with Monero, which requires about an hour to synchronize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does Monero require synchronization, but Bitcoin doesn't?

If you want to run a Bitcoin *full node* you still have to synchronize the blockchain and if you have a wallet loaded it still needs to scan the blockchain.

> ...(for example electrum wallet)

An Electrum wallet is not a full node, hence this is a poor comparison. If you want an Electrum like experience, Monero has comparable *light wallet* implementations.